# How to pass a string or string equivalent between C# and C++ that is in a struct?

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I have a struct that I've defined in both C# and C++ that looks like so:

**C#**

```
Public struct Part{
    public int number;
    public string name;
}
```

**C++**

```
struct Part{
    int number;
    std::string name;
}
```

I have a function that will do many things, but for the sake of simplicity, it will change around the part that was passed in.

**C#**

```
[DllImport(@"Part.Interface.dll")]
private static extern void _ChangeAStruct(ref Part part);

public void PassAStruct(){
    Part part = new Part();
    _ChangeAStruct(ref part);
}
```

**C++**

```
extern "C" __declspec(ddlexport) void __cdecl _ChangeAStruct(Part &part) {
    part.number = 42;
    part.name = "I am a struct";
}
```

On the C# side it successfully changes the number but the name returns as null. I have tried to `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` on the string but that didn't change anything.

How do I change the structs to pass back "I am a struct"? It has been mentioned that interop cannot handle std::string, but what can it handle?

Comment: I don't think P/Invoke has any support for `std::string`.

Comment: @Dan keeping it in the struct was my entire goal, I was unsure if having it in a struct changes how this would be approched

Comment: @Dan I actually took out that part about keeping old code. As it turns out we're expanding from here and using the old code as a base but not as a strict usage. So all I need now is the ability to pass back a string equivalent, but not necessarily a string itself.